# All occurrences of a regex get removed without using the "global" modifier

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I have the following text in the file sentence.txt

> Linux refers to the family of Unix-like computer operating systems
>   that use the Linux kernel.
>   Linux can be installed on a wide variety of computer hardware, ranging
>   from mobile phones, tablet computers and video game consoles, to
>   mainframes and supercomputers.                         Linux is
>   predominantly known for its use in servers.
>   It has a server market share ranging between 20–40%.
>   Most desktop computers run either Microsoft Windows or Mac OS X, with
>   Linux having anywhere from a low of an estimated 1–2% of the desktop
>   market to a high of an estimated 4.                 8%.
>   However, desktop use of Linux has become increasingly popular in
>   recent years, partly owing to the popular Ubuntu, Fedora, Mint, and
>   openSUSE distributions and the emergence of netbooks and smart phones
>   running an embedded Linux.
>   Linux can be installed on a wide variety of computer hardware, ranging
>   from mobile phones, tablet computers and video game consoles, to
>   mainframes and supercomputers.

In this text 2 sentences repeat. It is the last sentence. Actually I just copy-pasted the 2nd sentence to the end of the text so that I have 2 occurrences of the `mobile phones`

```
~$ grep mobile sentence.txt   
Linux can be installed on a wide variety of computer hardware, ranging from mobile   phones, tablet computers and video game consoles, to mainframes and supercomputers.  
Linux can be installed on a wide variety of computer hardware, ranging from mobile   phones, tablet computers and video game consoles, to mainframes and supercomputers.
```

Then I was wondering which occurrence would be deleted by the following regex:
`[^.]*mobile phones[^.]*\.`
I believe that the last occurrence should be removed due to the back tracking. To verify this assumption and my understanding I applied the following:

```
:~$ sed  's/[^.]*mobile phones[^.]*\.//' sentence.txt > sentence2.txt
```

Notice that I did not use `g` so that it would replace the first occurrence found (I think it would be the last sentence).
But I see that both are removed!

```
~$ grep mobile sentence2.txt    
~$
```

What am I doing wrong here? 1) Is my understanding of the regex that the last sentence would match first wrong? 2) Why are both sentences removed without `g`?

Comment: First let's make sure that sentence2.txt contains anything at all. Does it?

Comment: @Marki:Yes it does contain the rest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding would be correct if the regex were applied to the file as a whole. That's not how `sed` rolls: it operates line by line instead. Thus the `g` modifier would only come into play if your regex could match multiple times *on the same line*. In your case,  the substitution was applied only once to each line so naturally both instances were removed.

Slurp the whole file instead and see the difference:

```
perl -p0777e 's/[^.]*mobile phones[^.]*\.//' sentence.txt > sentence2.txt
```